# How to store partitions with latest data on one disk and historical data on another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I am going to partition my data by date.

Can I separate latest data from historical data on daily basis?

I.e. I want rolling date window - say latest 30 days of data  on one physical disk and the rest of them (older than that) on the another physical disk.

How do I roll it given the date data comes once in the morning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely possible, when you define the partition schema, you indicate which file group each partition within that schema resides on.

The issue will come when you are rolling the data and need an entire partition moved from one disk to another - that operation will have to be performed carefully and depending on the data quantities could take some time.

Given only 2 physical disks are being mentioned, what is driving the need for that split?

Comment: the split is due to the tables are too large and the queries are taking more and more time as it starts to scan more often rather than seek. adding indexes will blow up the db as each index candidate itself is about 20Gb and will grow. 80% of queries are going through past 2-3 days of data. 15% through past month and the rest is through all data... my idea is to speed up those 80% by not having indexes but rather partition data so the last week of data will be returning relatively fast for all queries.

Comment: sorry Andrew I had to edit my question. How do I go about the rolling process. Need simple list of actions (how do I move expired day to historical partition, how do I add new day into latest days partition, what could be the problem here). just simplified instruction will do. I then google the details. thanks

Comment: Partitioning does not outmatch index performance, if you are looking for an alternative which would be simpler - consider using a filtered index. Filter it to support the last 30 days only. That would provide faster response on that section of the data without requiring the whole table to be indexed. Partitioning is really about rolling in new data / rolling out old data - it is not a query performance panacea.

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning on two disks is not going to solve your performance issue because of the extra IO which will be involved in moving the data between disks, removing data from partition, updating indexes and the labor involved in verifing all data has been moved.

Is your data clustered on a date column?  You state that 80% of the queries are for the last two days so if your data was clustered on date then the IO would be essentially a sequential read.

Indexes, filtered or partitioned, will only point to the cluster or heap rows which contain the data and will result in random IO if the data is not in date sequence.  An index ordered and filtered on date which includes all columns of the table will be a good performance boost if you cannot cluster the table on date.

If you cannot make changes to the table structure and the table is not clustered on date I suggest:

- Move all table data to one set of
  disks.

  Use the other set of disk as index
  only
- Create a filtered index which spans a
  date range of three days.  Include
  all columns of the table
- Create a filtered index which spans a
  date range of the next three days. 
  Include all columns of the table
- Create a filtered index which spans a
  date range of the next three days. 
  Include all columns of the table
- Six days after you created the first
  index drop that index and create two
  filtered indexes which spans a date
  range of three days.  Include all
  columns of the table
- Repeat dropping and creating indexes.
- Automate this process with SQL Agent

  Monitor the index creation with
  alerts

The only way to prove whether any change results in an improvement is to have a benchmark of before and after.

Comment: thank you. your advice is brilliant. i need to think about it as some of the steps arent available (SQL agent and alerts and stats on indices use - DBA functionality is supposed to be carried by another team but they arent very helpful). all the table have clustered IDs and they are added on one day basis so in theory all dates are sequential on the disk as if it was a clustered index on the Date. but I am not sure if SQL picking this up all the time.